# How to separate strings from a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have 2 columns:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABCSD |
| 2 | SSNFs |
| 3 CVY KIP |  |
| 4 MSSSQ |  |
| 5 | ABCSD |
| 6 MMS LLS |  |
| 7 | QQLL |

This is an example actual files contains these type of cases in 1000+ rows.
I want to separate all the alphabets from column A and get them as output in column B:
Expected Output:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABCSD |
| 2 | SSNFs |
| 3 | CVY KIP |
| 4 | MSSSQ |
| 5 | ABCSD |
| 6 | MMS LLS |
| 7 | QQLL |

So Far I have tried this which works but looking for a better way:

```
df['B2'] = df['A'].str.split(' ').str[1:]

def try_join(l):
    try:
        return ' '.join(map(str, l))
    except TypeError:
        return np.nan
df['B2'] = [try_join(l) for l in df['B2']]

df = df.replace('', np.nan)
append=df['B2']
df['B']=df['B'].combine_first(append)
df['A']=[str(x).split(' ')[0] for x in df['A']]
df.drop(['B2'],axis=1,inplace=True)
df
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Edited , you can see my approach now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try as follows.

- *Either* use [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) with two named capture groups (generic: `(?P<name>...)`) as `A` and `B`. First one for the digit(s) at the start, second one for the rest of the string. (You can easily adjust these patterns if your actual strings are less straightforward.) Finally, drop the added index level (`1`) by using [`df.droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html).
- *Or* use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `n=1` and `expand=True` and rename the columns (`0` and `1` to `A` and `B`).
- Either option can be placed inside [`df.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) with `overwrite=True` to get the desired outcome.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'A': {0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3 CVY KIP', 3: '4 MSSSQ', 
              4: '5', 5: '6 MMS LLS', 6: '7'}, 
        'B': {0: 'ABCSD', 1: 'SSNFs', 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan, 
              4: 'ABCSD', 5: np.nan, 6: 'QQLL'}
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.update(df.A.str.extractall(r'(?P<A>^\d+)\s(?P<B>.*)').droplevel(1), 
          overwrite=True)

# or in this case probably easier:
# df.update(df.A.str.split(pat=' ', n=1, expand=True)\
#          .rename(columns={0:'A',1:'B'}),overwrite=True)

df['A'] = df.A.astype(int)

print(df)

   A        B
0  1    ABCSD
1  2    SSNFs
2  3  CVY KIP
3  4    MSSSQ
4  5    ABCSD
5  6  MMS LLS
6  7     QQLL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split on `' '` as it seems that the numeric value is always at the beginning and the text is after a space.

```
split = df.A.str.split(' ', 1)
df.loc[df.B.isnull(), 'B'] = split.str[1]
df.loc[:, 'A'] = split.str[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.split()` if your number appears first.

```
df['A'].str.split(n=1,expand=True).set_axis(df.columns,axis=1).combine_first(df)
```

or

```
df['A'].str.extract(r'(?P<A>\d+) (?P<B>[A-Za-z ]+)').combine_first(df)
```

Output:

```
   A        B
0  1    ABCSD
1  2    SSNFs
2  3  CVY KIP
3  4    MSSSQ
4  5    ABCSD
5  6  MMS LLS
6  7     QQLL
```